# How can I select all elements except those inside a particular div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here's my markup:

```
 <div class="car">
    <div class="make">NISSAN</div>
    <div class="model">MICRA</div>
</div>
<div class="discontinued">
    <div class="car">
        <div class="make">FORD</div>
        <div class="model">MONDEO</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="car">
    <div class="make">HONDA</div>
    <div class="model">INTEGRA</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="car">
    <div class="make">PEUGEOT</div>
    <div class="model">206</div>
</div>
<div class="car">
    <div class="make">TOYOTA</div>
    <div class="model">COROLLA</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to find a way to select all the makes of cars except those that are inside a div with the class `discontinued`.

I tried the following:

```
div:not(.discontinued) .make
```

...but this still included `FORD`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all `.car` except within `.discontinued`(you can do it by using [`:not` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) ) and then select all `.make` within it.

```css
:not(.discontinued) > .car .make {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
  <div class="make">NISSAN</div>
  <div class="model">MICRA</div>
</div>
<div class="discontinued">
  <div class="car">
    <div class="make">FORD</div>
    <div class="model">MONDEO</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="car">
  <div class="make">HONDA</div>
  <div class="model">INTEGRA</div>
</div>
<div class="car">
  <div class="make">PEUGEOT</div>
  <div class="model">206</div>
</div>
<div class="car">
  <div class="make">TOYOTA</div>
  <div class="model">COROLLA</div>
</div>
```